# df command works in terminal, but not in bash script

Tags: bash, redhat, linux-disk-free

I found the code below on a website.  I know what it does and understand it, but I can't get it to work correctly.  When I run it in Redhat 6.10, I get an error stating, "line 6: [: /: integer expression expected".

When I run the df code from the CURRENT variable in the terminal it outputs "21".  When it's in the script, it outputs "/".

What I'm trying to get it to do is e-mail me if the "/" directory gets over 50%.  Any ideas why the df portion of the code is working in the terminal, but not in the script?

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
THRESHOLD=50

if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ] ; then
        mail -s 'Disk Space Alert' E-MAIL REMOVED << EOF
Your root partition remaining free space is critically low. Used: $CURRENT%
EOF
fi
```

Comment: Break the command down into shorter and shorter parts, run it in and out of the script, and see what's different. You could also try `type df`, in and out of the script, to see if it uses a different `df`.

Comment: You can tell `df` what to output by choosing `--output[=FIELD_LIST]`, e.g. `df / --output=pcent`.

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
CURRENT=$(df / --output=pcent | tail -n1 | sed 's/%//g')
```

Comment: When I type in "type df" in both the terminal and the script it says df is in /bin/df.  I've broken the portion of the CURRENT script down and I get a return of 21 from terminal.  When I do it in the script it gives me the integer error.  When I try to use the --output=pcent, I get "line 6: [: /: integer expression expected"